# Using-declaration for base class constructors

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++11, inheritance

At first sight, `using` is used to import a specific function (such as `using std::cout` to the scope). But this `using` actually imports all the constructors of base class to the derived class. What's actually behind the scene of this `using` declaration?

```
template< typename T >
class Vec : public std::vector< T >
{
public:
    using std::vector<T>::vector;  // ?

    //...
};
```

Comment: There's nothing "behind" it. That's what it does.

Comment: When you ask *What's actually behind the scene*, are you trying to find out why the standard defines it that way, or are you trying to find out where it is useful?

Comment: Perhaps it just looks a bit different from what I've used and understood. It imports all constructors (instead of a specific function). Also, as it's public inherited, supposedly all the base class constructors should have been available already (ie why need `using`).  thanks

Comment: *[...] should have been available already [...]* -- @artm As I observed, semantically equivalent constructors that take arguments are not available through the name of the derived class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As it's `public` inherited, supposedly all the base class constructors
> should have been available already (ie why need `using`)?

**No**, constructors of the base class are not inherited by default. A detailed explanation can be found in the following discussions:

- [Why are constructors not
  inherited?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/197893/why-are-constructors-not-inherited)
- [Why aren't C++ constructors
  inherited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6710174/why-arent-c-constructors-inherited)

---

> What's actually behind the scene of this `using` declaration?

From *[cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration)*, `using` does

> 1. Using-declarations can be used to introduce namespace members into
>    other namespaces and block scopes, or **to introduce base class**
>    **members into derived class definitions.**
> 2. [...] ([c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) specific...)

Also while [inheritance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Inheriting_constructors):

> If the using-declaration refers to a constructor of a direct base of
> the class being defined (e.g. `using Base::Base;`), **all constructors
> of that base** (ignoring member access) **are made visible to overload
> resolution when initializing the derived class**.